# Global Constant in .dat file

Tags: c++, constants

I have a file, called "Values.dat", which contains several parameters value that I have to use as global constants in my code. To do so I created an header file "Parameters.h":

```
#ifndef _PARAMETERS_
#define _PARAMETERS_

#include <fstream>

struct Parameters {
  double A;
  double B;
  //other parameters
  Parameters() {
   std::ifstream FileInput("Values.dat");
   FileInput >> A;
   FileInput >> B;
   //read other parameters
  }
};

const Parameters PAR;

#endif
```

and then I access the parameters value using PAR.A, PAR.B, etc...

I think this is not a very smart way to make constant the parameters I have, but I can't think of any other way... Have you got any suggestion? 
I have performance issues and can't use c++11 because I'm stuck with a really old machine and can't upgrade it.

Sorry for my bad english.

Thanks in advance

Comment: if you performance of your machine is so bad can't update gcc to use C++11 you have more pressing problems. Unless this is hw

Comment: `_PARAMETERS_` is an implementation reserved identifier you must not use.